# rendering difference when using class vs id selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having issues with rendering a 'chat bubble' in a div.

[See Demo Here](http://rlemon.com/test.html)

When the CSS rules for the bubble container are applied using a className as the selector it is rendered differently then when the ID is the selector (pure CSS or JQuery, so It is not a JQuery issue).

Here is the CSS

```
#tweetBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 72px;
    right: 158px;
    display: none;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
}
.tweetBox-class {
    position: absolute;
    top: 72px;
    right: 158px;
    display: none;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
}
```

as you can see from the example, when the class selector is used the width of the container goes all wonky.

Why is there a difference in the rendering when using ID selectors VS Class selectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have other classes in your stylesheet and they're being applied to your container in your JavaScript code:

```js
function sID(message) {
    var b = $("<div id='tweetBox' />"); 
    $("#header").html("").append(b);
    b.addClass("triangle-right right");
    b.html(message).fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(300);
}
function sCLASS(message) {
    var b = $("<div />");   
    $("#header").html("").append(b);
    b.addClass("tweetBox-class triangle-right right");
    b.html(message).fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(300);
}
```

So the browser has to take all those classes into account when rendering your container.

The rule with the ID selector overrides every other rule with only class selectors, while the one with the class selector is applied first since it comes first before your other classes, and some styles become overridden by the other classes as they occur later in your stylesheet.

Comment: Is that always the case ID > CLASS for priority?

Comment: @minitech: No, because it's totally wrong. A single ID selector is more specific than any number of class selectors. The spec doesn't say an ID is worth 100 points or a class is worth 10 points. It's telling you that an ID selector is less specific than an ID + class selector.

Comment: @minitech: [From the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity): "Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity." Note it says "a number system with a large base", so even if you're adding up numbers rather than concatenating them, you're not doing it in base 10. That means 100 in whatever large base is not actually a hundred and 10 is not ten.

Comment: Gee, thanks for the inundation of comments and sarcasm. I found it very useful. A fiddle would have sufficed to be productive.

Comment: @minitech: I didn't mean to be condescending back then, but it seems I came across as such, and looking back I did sound like it. Sorry about that :|

Comment: @BoltClock: No, it's okay :) `window.history` now. (And congratulations on becoming a moderator, by the way!)